# Angular binding radio to boolean doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have a form using AngularJS (classic one) that should display or not a CompanyName field only if the User is a Company.

By default the "Individual" radio should be selected:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
  <h4>You are:</h4> 
  Name <input ng-model="user.name">
  <h5>Individual or Company?</h5>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="company" ng-model="user.isCompany" ng-value=true> a company = '{{user.isCompany}}'<br>
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="individ" checked > an individual<br>

  <div ng-show="user.isCompany">
    Company Name <input ng-model="user.companyName">
  </div>
</body>
```

How to bind to the radio checked value in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `ng-model` and `ng-value` to both inputs, so when you will click again on "an individual", the company form will disapear.

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-init="user.isCompany = false">
  <h4>You are:</h4> 
  Name <input ng-model="user.name">
  <h5>Individual or Company?</h5>

  <input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="user.isCompany" ng-value="true"> a company = '{{user.isCompany}}'<br>
  <input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="user.isCompany" ng-value="false"> an individual<br>

  <div ng-show="user.isCompany">
    Company Name <input ng-model="user.companyName">
  </div>
</body>
```

---

*Note that I added `ng-init="user.isCompany = false"` in `<body>`. You can also move it to your controller to make it cleaner:*

```
$scope.user = { ..., 'isCompany': false };
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
  <h4>You are:</h4> 
  Name <input ng-model="user.name">
  <h5>Individual or Company?</h5>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="company" ng-model="user.isCompany" ng-value="true"> a company = '{{user.isCompany}}'<br>
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="individ" ng-init="user.isCompany=false" ng-model="user.isCompany" checked ng-value="false"> an individual<br>

  <div ng-show="user.isCompany">
    Company Name <input ng-model="user.companyName">
  </div>
</body>
```